# SAPUI5 - 'getService' of undefined

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am working on variant management using shell. I got 'getService' of undefined error in FLP. After adding below libraries, It worked.

Index.html

```
    <script>
    window["sap-ushell-config"] = {
        defaultRenderer : "fiori2",
        renderers: {
            fiori2: {
                componentData: {
                    config: {
                        search: "hidden"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        applications: {
            "OrderTracking-display": {
                additionalInformation: "SAPUI5.Component=orders",
                applicationType: "URL",
                url: ".",
                title: "Order Tracking"
            }
        }
    };
</script>

  <script src="/sap/public/bc/ui5_ui5/resources/sap/ushell_abap/bootstrap/abap.js" id="sap-ushell-bootstrap"></script>  

  <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ushell, sap.collaboration, sap.m, sap.ui.commons, 
   sap.ui.layout, sap.ui.ux3"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
  data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
  data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"orders": "."}'
  data-sap-ui-frameOptions="trusted">
```

manifest.json

```
    "sap.ui5": {
    "rootView": {
        "viewName": "orders.view.App",
        "type": "XML",
        "async": true,
        "id": "app"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "minUI5Version": "1.42.0",
        "libs": {
            "sap.ui.core": {},
            "sap.m": {},
            "sap.f": {},
            "sap.ushell": {},
            "sap.collaboration": {
                "lazy": true
            }
        }
    },
    "contentDensities": {
        "compact": true,
        "cozy": true
    },
    "models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "orders.i18n.i18n"
            }
        },
        "": {
            "dataSource": "mainService",
            "preload": true
        }
    },
    "services": {
        "ShellUIService": {
            "factoryName": "sap.ushell.ui5service.ShellUIService",
            "lazy": false,
            "settings": {
                "setHierarchy": "auto",
                "setTitle": "auto"
            }
        }
    },
```

But I couldn't find ui5service.ShellUIService under sap.ushell. Also popups & date pickers is not working. How to make both sap.ushell.ui5service & 
sap.ushell.services libraries work.

Below are the errors I get

[Error -1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drWkU.png)

[Error -2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Nxg.png)

There is no 'ui5service' under 'ushell'

[sap.ushell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccMd6.png)

Comment: Please show us the code that you are using in your app.
 
The file that you showed is for running an app during development and not for running the app from a launchpad.

Comment: @SAPFioriCrew I have edited my question. This is the index file I am using for running the application in launchpad

Answer (score 0):

The index.html file is used to run an app from the WebIDE in test mode during development. A local launchpad called a Sandbox is created to run the app but not all services from launchpad (cloud or abap) are available.

The libraries that the app needs must be defined in the javascript files where they are needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Upgrading SAPUI version from 740 to 752 made it to work.